# How to create a tree node with menu, submenu, child, item

Tags: c#

I want to create a program that will get data from an excel sheet shows in 4 combo box with a drop drown list.

For example, if I choose menu1, drop list will the corresponding submenu (i.e, submenu11 & submenu12) rather than showing all other submenus.

Again, once selecting submenu11, drop down list will show only the child111 & child112.

[image]

[image]

I have already imported the data from excel but unable to sort data in a combo box.

```
private void btnLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string stringconn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + tbxSelect.Text + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;\";";
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(stringconn);
        if (tbxSelect.Text != "")
        {
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [" + tbxChoice.Text + "$]", conn);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            //dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                string firstRow = dt.Rows[i]["A"].ToString();


                if (firstRow != "")
                {
                    cmbRow1.Items.Add(firstRow);

                    if (!firstRow.Equals(Row1))
                    {
                        //essageBox.Show(firstRow);
                    }

                    else
                        RowIndex_1++;

                    Row1 = firstRow;
                }
            }


            MessageBox.Show(RowIndex_1.ToString());

            for (int j = 0; j < dt.Rows.Count; j++)
            {
                string secondRow = dt.Rows[j]["B"].ToString();

                if (secondRow != "")
                    cmbRow2.Items.Add(secondRow);
            }

            for (int k = 0; k < dt.Rows.Count; k++)
            {
                string secondRow = dt.Rows[k]["C"].ToString();

                if (secondRow != "")
                    cmbRow3.Items.Add(secondRow);
            }

            for (int l = 0; l < dt.Rows.Count; l++)
            {
                string secondRow = dt.Rows[l]["D"].ToString();

                if (secondRow != "")
                    cmbRow4.Items.Add(secondRow);
            }

            for (int m = 0; m < dt.Rows.Count; m++)
            {
                string secondRow = dt.Rows[m]["E"].ToString();

                if (secondRow != "") ;
                    //cmbRow5.Items.Add(secondRow);
            }


            conn.Close();
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Er");
```

}

Comment: Typically we query the dB when the user makes a selection; load only the first combo box and attach a selectedindexchanged event handler tout treat will fill the second box when something is chosen for the first etc

Comment: Thanks for your help. But i have not so much knowledge in c#. If you give some coding help then it's very helpful for me.